# print information from the database on a predefined printed form

Tags: php, html, forms, printing

I want to print information from the database on a predefined printed form.

I have a printed form and i have got all information related to that form in the database. I would like to print that information at proper places on the form. I just want to print the information and not other predefined instructions. For example, in the below form only the blue text would change from the database

[image]

Can anyone please suggest a way to do this? Thanks for help

Comment: You mean *print*, like on paper…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ryan for suggesting EZPDF class and everyone else for responses.

I find EZPDF class (suggested by Ryan) little bit tricky and thought it might take much time. So, I went with different approach. I created pdf with fillable form (using Adobe Acrobat) and then used [createFDF](http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/tutorial.php)  to fill in the places and print the form

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one of many pdf classes.  Start by putting the pdf in the background and then call the text from the database and place it where you want.  I'm a fan of the [EZPDF Class](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/).  It's easy to use, well documented, and will do exactly what you're looking for. I've done it many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS alignment and positioning of data on web page. As Ryan said before, PDF classes will help you through this. Is your data goes directly to printing after retrieval from database?